# Solaris 10 installation on KVM constantly reboot

Tags: solaris, kvm, qemu

Successfully installed Solaris 10 sparc on KVM. However when I restarted the VM it doesn't go to login screen but just constantly reboots. I've read different documents [link1](http://dcvan24.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/solaris-vm-keeps-rebooting-on-openstack/) [link2](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/solaris-10-guest-endless-reboot-under-kvm-qemu-602987/) [link3](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Solaris_Guests) but none of their solutions helped. I used Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Solaris using Virt-Manager. I updated qemu-kvm  to the latest version (2.0) as the one installed in Ubuntu is quite old. I have the following configuration below in setting up Solaris in virt-manager, if this helps.

```
ISO - sol-10-u11-ga-sparc-dvd.iso


Memory: 2GB
Processors: 1 
Hard Disk: raw, 
cache=writeback, IDE
Network: E1000
Sound: ac97
OS Type: Other OS types (other) choose Solaris 10
Boot order: Disk 'ide0', CD-ROM
Tablet for Pointer: No
Use local time for RTC: Yes
```

Comment: Does it always reboot at the same point in the boot process? What point is that? Can you see anything on the console or access any logs?

Comment: yes, it lets me choose to boot either to solaris or a failsafe option and after a few seconds when i chose one of those options it will go back to that point again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Solaris x86 after upgrading QEMU from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0. A quick *git bisect* session on QEMU source repository proved [this](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=commit;h=f8e6a11aecc96e9d8a84f17d7c07019471714e20) commit to be the culprit:

```
target-i386: Set model=6 on qemu64 & qemu32 CPU models
```

Apparently Solaris 10 doesn't like this a lot (Solaris 11 works fine).

While this probably doesn't help your case a lot, you might want to try:

- doing a QEMU *git bisect* for your issue,
- downgrading QEMU to an older branch (unless you have your reasons to use version 2.0).

Comment: Are you really running a Solaris kernel on SPARC ? If true, how is this "target-i386" issue related to the SPARC architecture ?

Comment: @jlliagre Good point, thanks. I've missed the SPARC part. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris10 X86 works fine on new Qemu-3.1.0 and libvirt-4.9
I have tried to "backport" from VirtualBox to qemu but fail, a fresh install works well.

With the sparc version I have only fails..simply the boot process won't start.

I have installed from DVD and using the serial console,fs is ufs(not tried zfs but I think will work)

Remind: On some cpu may be not work fine and panic

If someone need,this is the xml dump,only edit the mac address with correct values,the disk image path and wathever you want.

```
<domain type='kvm' id='12'>
  <name>solaris10</name>
  <uuid>c76c491e-c264-4939-8333-835dae48405f</uuid>
  <title>solaris10</title>
  <description>Virtual machine solaris10 with serial</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>3145728</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>3145728</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc'>hvm</type>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='partial'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='floppy'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <target dev='fda' bus='fdc'/>
      <alias name='fdc0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide' tray='open'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='unsafe'/>
      <source file='/home/myname/.local/share/libvirt/images/solaris10.qcow2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='fdc' index='0'>
      <alias name='fdc0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='CH:AN:GE:ME:PL:EASE'/>
      <source bridge='bridge0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/0'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input3'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='it'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
      <gl enable='no' rendernode='/dev/dri/renderD128'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='vmvga' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='none'/>
  </devices>
</domain>
```